# How I can detect irregular shapes and remove from image with opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, noise

I'm using opencv library in Python and i have this issue.
I have this image ,that i previously i removed a lot of noise, but in this image there are a lot of irregular shape that i want to remove.

For example :

Im using this image:

[image: start image]

For get the start image i use this code:

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("Image.png")
## Heading ##
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (7, 7))
inverted_thresh = 255 - thresh
dilate = cv2.dilate(inverted_thresh, kernel, iterations=3)

cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ROI = thresh[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    data = pytesseract.image_to_string(ROI, lang='eng', config='--psm 6').lower()

sub = cv2.subtract(~gray, dilate)


# In[4]:


# Sobel Edge Detection
sobelx = cv2.Sobel(src=sub, ddepth=cv2.CV_64F, dx=1, dy=0, ksize=5)  # Sobel Edge Detection on the X axis
sobely = cv2.Sobel(src=sub, ddepth=cv2.CV_64F, dx=0, dy=1, ksize=5)  # Sobel Edge Detection on the Y axis
sobelxy = cv2.Sobel(src=sub, ddepth=cv2.CV_64F, dx=1, dy=1, ksize=5)  # Combined X and Y Sobel Edge Detection

# In[8]:


# Canny Edge Detection
edges = cv2.Canny(image=sub, threshold1=45, threshold2=55)  # Display Canny Edge Detection Image
cv2.imshow('Canny Edge Detection', edges)
```

And i would to get this result

[image: desired result]

How i can get this result?

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Comment: I update the question , but i show how  I get the startimage and i have no idea how to get the desidered result

Comment: What's the purpose of `pytesseract` here? There is no text present in the image.

Comment: when i do this istruction  "image = cv2.imread("Image.png")" Image.png has text . I use pytesseract  because  i need the text for other purpos but i need to remove this from the image

Comment: The flag `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL` would find only the external contours. You have it all.

Answer (score 0):

If you know min line length of the border, you can easy filter other elements.

```py
import cv2
gray = cv2.imread("Image.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

minLineWidth = 397

hKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (minLineWidth, 1))
vKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, minLineWidth))

hGray = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, hKernel)
vGray = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vKernel)

gray = cv2.bitwise_or(hGray, vGray)

cv2.imshow("gray", gray)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Result image:
[image: Result image]

If you don't know min line length, you can use [probabilistic hough transform](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html) to find all lines. Then you can filter lines by angle and find min repeated line length. After you can apply suggested code or just draw filtered lines.

> P.S. Try first of all google your problem. Ex: `stackoverflow filter horizontal lines from image`. On first link you can find good approaches of your problem.